# SQL Server: SELECT Everything WHEN Variable is NULL

Tags: sql-server

I have code...

```
DECLARE @y AS INT = xxx; --IF THIS IS NULL THEN WE WANT EVERYTHING RETURNED

SELECT column
FROM   table
WHERE  y >= @y;
```

How can I set this up so that `IF @y IS NULL` then the where clause is ignored and **everything is returned**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT some_column
FROM your_table
WHERE (@y is null or y >= @y)
```